# Lazy loading NUXT + vue-youtube component

Tags: lazy-loading, vue-component, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Loading several videos using NUXT and vue-youtube (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-youtube) applying lazy load

I've been looking for days about that but no information about how to lazy load videos programming in NUXT in Universal mode (no spa) but were not able to get any clue

This is the component containing a v-card where the code is embedded

```
<youtube
      ref="youtube"
      :video-id="videoId"
      :player-vars="{autoplay:0, modestbranding:1, showinfo: 0, rel:0, origin: 'https://example.com', widget_referrer: 'https://example.com'}"
      fit-parent
      @playing="playing"
      @paused="paused"
      @ended="ended"
    />
```

lazy loading or any other way to get the screen completed faster